# multiple row saving to DB table

Tags: php, mysql

I have to save more than one row of data into database table.

I wrote this code for that. But when i run this code, two rows will be saved into two rows of db table, but every other row is same as the last row data.

i.e. that is the last row data is overwriting every other row data.

```
$values = array();

if (isset($_POST['sub_save'])) {
    $row_count = $_POST['rowcount'];

    while ($row_count > 0) {
        for ($r = 1; $r <= 2; $r++) {
            $val = $_POST['txt'.$row_count.$r];
            $values[] = $val;
        }

        $row_count = $row_count - 1;
        $sql = "insert into timesheet_entry (name, address) values ('$values[0]', '$values[1]')";

        if (mysql_query($sql)) {
            echo "inserted";
        } else {
            echo "fail";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The way you are structuring the data in the posting HTML is *horrible* and likely the cause of the problem here.

Comment: could tell me where should i change my code?

Comment: From the beginning - but I suspect that's not the answer you're looking for. Don't try to amalgamate pre-generated, surrogate keys into a composite key (or if you must, at least delimit the components).

Comment: omg im a begginer can you tell me in a simpler way!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I can't tell you how you you should structure unless I know a lot more about it.

Comment: what part u dont understand in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't resetting your values array inside the loop so values[0] and values[1] will always have the first to values.

```
if (isset($_POST['sub_save'])) {
    $row_count = $_POST['rowcount'];

    while ($row_count > 0) {
        $values = array();
        for ($r = 1; $r <= 2; $r++) {
            $val = $_POST['txt'.$row_count.$r];
            $values[] = $val;
        }

        $row_count = $row_count - 1;
        $sql = "insert into timesheet_entry (name, address) values ('$values[0]', '$values[1]')";

        if (mysql_query($sql)) {
            echo "inserted";
        } else {
            echo "fail";
        }
    }
}
```

On a sidenote I would recommend looking into the PDO extension and parameterised queries as mysql_ is deprecated and the above code is vulnerable to SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", ""); 
$db = mysqli_select_db("dbname");

if (mysqli_query($sql)) {
   echo "inserted";
} else {
   echo "fail";
}
```

Comment: ok i will correct it but the problem is rows are saving but the last row data overwriting the above rows..can you help me with that?